# Infinite Scroll fires multiple times in a row

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I've got infinite scroll setup for a overflowing div element. I've enabled a binder to attach to this div and also enabled the local behavior. Still I'm seeing weird results as when the first infinite scroll is triggered, it triggers multiple times, and if I keep scrolling it'll fires again.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here's a demo tumblr to illustrate the problem: http://infinitescrolldebug.tumblr.com

```
var $wall = $( ".posts" )

$wall.infinitescroll({
    behavior: 'local',
    binder: $('#content-container'),

    navSelector: "#pagination",
    nextSelector: "#pagination .next a",
    itemSelector: ".posts article",
    bufferPx: $(window).height() * 2,
    errorCallback: function() {
    }
},

function ( newElements ) {
    var opts = $wall.data( "infinitescroll" ).options,
        $elems = $( newElements );

    console.log('infinite scroll fired');
});
```